Track by multiple parameters with @for in Angular 18
Angular introduced a new notation for for loops with @for(x of y; track x).
I am looping through a list of objects that will have some properties modified over time. I want to track those properties. This is what I tried, which seems to work but I'm not 100% sure it does what I think it does :
@for (device of devices(); track device.foo && device.bar) {
    // ...
}

If device.foo or device.bar gets updated in one of the objects in the list, I want my angular to re-render the item in the list.
From what I found, the docs does not give any multi-properties examples :
https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow#track-for-calculating-difference-of-two-collections

track syntax is similar to *ngFor directive. You can define your custom track function like this:


myCustomTrackBy(index: number, item: DeviceModel): string {
    return `${index}-${item.foo}-${item.bar}`;
}
@for (device of devices(); track myCustomTrackBy($index, device)) {
    // ...
}



And also keep in mind that using devices() function to retrieve items will negatively affect performance, because function/getters calls inside the template will be recalculated on every angular change detection tick. You'd better work with stream and use it with async pipe: @for (devices$ | async; track myCustomTrackBy(...)).

This worked for me:
@for (device of devices(); track { Prop1: device.foo, Prop2: device.bar }) {
    // ...
}

The doc says:

The value of the track expression determines a key used to associate array items with the views in the DOM. Having clear indication of the item identity allows Angular to execute a minimal set of DOM operations as items are added, removed or moved in a collection.
To optimize performance, especially in loops over immutable data, ensure the track expression is effectively used to identify each item uniquely. Because of the potential for poor performance, the track expression is required for the @for loops.
For collections that remain static, track $index provides a straightforward tracking mechanism. For dynamic collections experiencing additions, deletions, or reordering, opt for a unique property of each item as the tracking key.

My list changes depending upon the value of other controls on the page, so using an object to make up the key that consists of the properties that make each item unique made sense.
You can use track $index if your list doesn't change.
